# How to trigger the onclick / onchange event for a already selected option clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get option value of an already selected option in the select choice list. How can I make it possible. Here is my code snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getCusineType").bind('click', function() {
         alert($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
    $("#getCusineType").bind('focusout', function() {
         alert($(this).find('option:selected').val());
    });
    function getCusineType(){
      var getCusineType = $('#getCusineType').val();
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="getCusineType" onchange="getCusineType()">
   <option value="1">Indian</option>
   <option value="2">American</option>
   <option value="3">Italian</option>
   <option value="4">General</option>                 
 </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: @vishnuSadanandan, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `selected` option `value`:

```
var value=$("#getCusineType").val();
```

or `text`

```
var text=$("#getCusineType option:selected").text();
```

If you want to get the selected value after `change` event, you should bind a `change` event handler.

```
$("#getCusineType").change(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

```js
console.log("Value is: "+$('#getCusineType').val());
console.log("Text is: "+$("#getCusineType option:selected").text());
$("select").click(function() {
       console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="getCusineType">
         <option value="1">Indian</option>
         <option value="2">American</option>
         <option value="3">Italian</option>
         <option value="4">General</option>                 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply way to trigger the on change event

```
 $(function(){
      $("#getCusineType").on('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
      }).trigger('change');
    });
```